# Why IKEv2 uses UDP and not TCP?

Tags: ipsec

As per the IKEv2 [RFC 7296](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296), it is a reliable protocol.

> Since UDP is a datagram (unreliable) protocol, IKE includes in its
> definition recovery from transmission errors, including packet loss,
> packet replay, and packet forgery.

Furthermore, it also has retransmission timers ([Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#section-2.1)), sequence numbers in the form of message id ([Section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#section-2.2)) and window size ([Section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#section-2.3)). Although, the RFC clearly mentions that the purpose of window size is not to achieve congestion control.

> The window size is normally a (possibly configurable) property of a
> particular implementation, and is not related to congestion control
> (unlike the window size in TCP, for example).

The question that I have is that why does IKEv2 uses UDP, and not leverage TCP instead?

Comment: This question is about networking rather than security.

Comment: @multithr3at3d I just realized after posting the question. Even though it's IKE, but it has nothing to do with security per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason is **backward compatibility with IKEv1**. Another is **compatibility with NAT traversal** (UDP encapsulation, [RFC 3948](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3948)) as that leverages the existing NAT mappings created by the IKE connection to transport ESP over NATs (doing this via TCP may impact performance severaly, see below).

However, it is now possible to use TCP encapsulation for IKEv2 and ESP (even tunneling in TLS is possible). This extension is defined in [RFC 8229](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8229) and is  intended as a fallback if a connection can't be established via UDP (e.g. because of firewalls).

As described in [section 12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8229#section-12) of that RFC, there could be several negative performance impacts when using it (e.g. TCP-in-TCP), so using UDP is generally preferable. Since it's a relatively new extension, support for it is not very widespread yet (the Linux kernel supports it since 5.6, which was released in March/April 2020).

Comment: RFC 8229 is something which I was not aware of :)